# FusedLocationProviderClient with Kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, fusedlocationproviderapi, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to request a new location with FusedLocationProviderClient and Kotlin Coroutines. This is my current setup:

```
class LocationProviderImpl(context: Context) : LocationProvider, CoroutineScope {

    private val TAG = this::class.java.simpleName

    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.IO

    private val fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    private val locationRequest = LocationRequest().apply {
        numUpdates = 1
        priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    }

    override suspend fun getLocation(): LatLng = suspendCoroutine {
        val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(result: LocationResult) {
                result.lastLocation.run {
                    val latLng = latitude at longitude
                    it.resume(latLng)
                }

                fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(this)
            }
        }

        try {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper())
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            throw NoLocationPermissionException()
        }
    }
}
```

But when trying to request a new location, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

However, if I would call Looper.prepare() (and Looper.quit() eventually) wouldn't it mean that I can call the function only once?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the way you set up your `coroutineContext`. Use this instead:

```
override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job
```

If you ever need the `IO` dispatcher, you can require it explicitly:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... blocking IO code ... }
```

To suspend the coroutine, call `suspendCancellableCoroutine`, otherwise you won't get any benefit from structured concurrency.

Another detail, don't write any code after `it.resume` in the `suspendCancellableCoroutine` block. If the dispatcher chooses to resume the coroutine immediately, within the `resume` call, that code won't execute until all the code of the coroutine has run (or at least until the next suspension point).

```
override fun onLocationResult(result: LocationResult) {
    fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(this)
    it.resume(result.lastLocation.run { latitude to longitude })
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `Dispatchers.Default` rather then IO for non blocking operations e.g. calculations

Comment: I don't see the relevance of this comment. OP used the `IO` dispatcher, the answer is explicit in stating that it is only for blocking IO operations, and nobody mentioned CPU-intensive operations.

Answer (score 3):

```
private val locationRequestGPS by lazy {
    LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setNumUpdates(1)
            .setExpirationDuration(1000)
}

private val locationRequestNETWORK by lazy {
    LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER)
            .setNumUpdates(1)
            .setExpirationDuration(1000)
}



suspend fun getLocation(context: Context, offsetMinutes: Int = 15): Location? = suspendCoroutine { task ->
    val ctx = context.applicationContext
    if (!ctx.isPermissionValid(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            && !ctx.isPermissionValid(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        task.resume(null)
    } else {
        val manager = ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        if (!LocationManagerCompat.isLocationEnabled(manager)) {
            task.resume(null)
        } else {
            val service = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(ctx)
            service.lastLocation
                    .addOnCompleteListener { locTask ->
                        if (locTask.result == null || System.currentTimeMillis() - locTask.result!!.time > offsetMinutes.minute) {
                            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                                task.resume(locationRequest(manager, service))
                            }
                        } else {
                            task.resume(locTask.result)
                        }

                    }
        }
    }
}

suspend fun getLocationLast(context: Context): Location? = suspendCoroutine { task ->
    val ctx = context.applicationContext
    if (!ctx.isPermissionValid(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            && !ctx.isPermissionValid(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        task.resume(null)
    } else {
        if (!LocationManagerCompat.isLocationEnabled(ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager)) {
            task.resume(null)
        } else {
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(ctx)
                    .lastLocation
                    .addOnCompleteListener { locTask ->
                        task.resume(locTask.result)
                    }
        }

    }
}

suspend fun locationRequest(locationManager: LocationManager, service: FusedLocationProviderClient): Location? = suspendCoroutine { task ->
    val callback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
            service.removeLocationUpdates(this)
            task.resume(p0?.lastLocation)
        }
    }

    when {
        locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) -> {
            service.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequestGPS, callback, Looper.getMainLooper())
        }
        locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) -> {
            service.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequestNETWORK, callback, Looper.getMainLooper())
        }
        else -> {
            task.resume(null)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not found ctx.isPermissionValid and offsetMinutes.minute

Answer (score 0):

By using `suspendCoroutine` you invoke the provided code on the dispatcher that called the suspended function during runtime. Since most dispatchers don't run on Looper threads (pretty much only `Dispatchers.MAIN` does) the call to `Looper.myLooper()` fails.

The documentation says you can replace `Looper.myLooper()` with `null` to invoke the callback on an unspecified thread. The built-in coroutine dispatcher will then make sure it is routed to the correct thread for resuming the execution.

EDIT: You might need to call `it.intercepted().resume(latLng)` to ensure the result is dispatched to the correct thread. I'm not entirely sure if the `suspendCoroutine` continuation is intercepted by default.

In addition you don't need to call `fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(this)` because you already set the number of updates in the `LocationRequest` to `1`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When passing in null I get the same exception again... The it.intercept() method is not available to me?!

Comment: "IllegalStateException  If looper is null and this method is executed in a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()." You'll need to wrap the `requestLocationUpdates` call inside of an `withContext(Dispatchers.MAIN) { ... }` block.